# Load Storyboard view without segue file - viewController names are encoded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to load explicitly a storyboard's view which doesn't have segue:

```
    NSStoryboard * sb = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myList" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
    OfflineOtpLoginVc* vc = [sb instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
```

However, it fails although a view with this name does exist in the storyBoard file.

So I printed the storyboard structure, and saw that instead of the explicit names of my viewControllers names included so that instead of `myViewController` I see `NSViewController-2JH-qK-ybH`. Perhaps anybody know how to make the reverse conversion ?

```
(lldb) po sb
NSStoryboard: 0x7f92f6122220
- bundle: /Applications/MyApp/Contents/Resources/myStoryBoard.storyboardc
- initial_controller: myList
- main_menu: MainMenu
- identifier_to_nib_name:
  - NSViewController-Aq4-0h-Tmf: NSViewController-Aq4-0h-Tmf
  - NSViewController-2JH-qK-ybH: NSViewController-2JH-qK-ybH
...
```

Comment: Are you sure "myViewController" matches the Storyboard ID and not just the class name?  (It also seems odd that your printout says the storyboard is named "myStoryBoard" when you open it as "myList".)

Comment: You're right, the term `myViewController` only refer to the class name, so I had to set `identity.storyboard ID` in order for this vc to get the name. thanks !